# How to enter data for 3 index parameter using CPLEX in java?

Tags: java, cplex

I'm working on job shop scheduling problem and i'm using Cplex in Java and want to define a binary decision variable `x[i][j][k]` with `i=(1..n)` with `n=number of job` , `j=(1..m)` with `m=number` of operation by job and `k=(1..M)` with `M=number` of machine.

And, i want to intialize this these kind of variables [image: decision variables]

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having tested, this snippet should intialize a 3D array of boolean decision variables:

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
IloNumVar[][][] x = new IloNumVar[n][][];
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x[i] = new IloNumVar[m][];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
          x[i][j] = cplex.boolVarArray(M);
        }     
     }
```

Take a look at the [CPLEX Java examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Examples/topics/exampleJava.html). Understanding these simple examples could even take less time than posting your question here.

Comment: An error in this two lines :                                                                       x[i][][] = new IloNumVar[m][];                                                                  x[i][j][] = cplex.boolVarArray(M);

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 Syntax error on token "]", byte expected
 Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after this token
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from IloIntVar[] to IloNumVar

Comment: how can i intialize a 5D array of boolean decison variables (example Yi1j1i2j2k)?

Comment: you just need to extend the logic of the above 3D example: IloNumVar[][][][][] my5dArray = new IloNumVar[n][][][][]; and so forth

Comment: Is the declaration of variable of 5D array is the same of 5D matrix in cplex ?